# How do I resolve a <subdomain pointing to a shared third party host> to my domain on that shared host?

Tags: dns, hosting, shared-hosting

I have asked my college to point example.college.edu to example.mydomain.com and they have done so by adding a CNAME record.

However, the problem is that example.college.edu points to the IP address of a shared server. Is it possible for it to point to the domain name, example.mydomain.com, and not the IP address at which example.mydomain.com is hosted?

And is there something I can do out of my host's cpanel which can resolve example.college.edu to my domain?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you would need to set up a proxy server on example.college.edu

For the second part you'd need some access to the server that example.college.edu is hosted.

Define the "Sorta" re-direction your college have made.

Comment: They added a CNAME record for example.college.edu to point to example.mydomain.com

Comment: What web hosting are you using? Ping example.college.edu and check it is pointing to the domain of your hosting, if it is then it sounds like a domain binding issue.

Comment: I'm using Dreamhost. both example.college.edu and example.mydomain.com ping to the same IP address. Also, nslookup on example.college.edu says that its alias is example.mydomain.com.

Comment: Is that the IP address of your host?
If so then make sure you've set up your domain on your web host
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Add_a_domain